# Opera (only) - margin of absolutely positioned child element pushes it up the next sibling, also absolutely positioned

Tags: css, opera, margin

I have quite simple markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="ta-container">
        <div id="gripper"></div>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And I style it like a basic chat window might look. Please see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavek/rdxN5/3/

This looks perfectly well in FF, Chrome, IE, but **not in Opera** (12.11, the latest now). The most confusing thing is how two absolutely positioned elements within container affect each other -- I cannot comprehend that.

I'd like to see possible solutions for this issue. Note: I prefer to avoid manipulating the *height* of div#content.

Comment: The textarea/div doesn't show correctly in my FF either. It's 5px too wide, expanding at the right side of the div.

Comment: Besides, I have no idea why you'd want to test for Opera: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Regarding FF: this is indeed true. But I sweat it wasn't so back when I posted it. Pretty sure, FF update brought something new..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the why for you, but you can correct it by doing away with the margins and make the top/right/bottom/left properties reflect where you want the edges placed:

http://jsfiddle.net/rdxN5/4/

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This is just a rough adjustment, you'll have to do a little fine-tuning on your own to get it to where it should be.

Comment: +1 for 'bottom: xx;' I don't see how could I overlook that:) Just tested and it works everywhere great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the Opera hack.

but, why are you using absolute position for that?

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/liccyfuentes/KbxJK/

HTML:
    
            
            
    
    ​
​
CSS:
    * {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

```
#container {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding:5px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;            
}

#main-content {
    min-height:248px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:188px;
}
textarea {
    float:left;
    width:188px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
​
```

Comment: @Licy, sorry I don't see what you mean by 'Opera hack'. I mentioned that I don't want to deal with hard-coded height & width. The reason (which I omitted) is  that #container will finally become resizable, so I want as much as possible to be done by layout engine for me.

Comment: as you can see, the height is flexible but! will have a min-height. You do not need to use position "absolute" or "relative" to achieve that type of behavior... let me know if you get it now, or need more help...

Comment: thanks for ideas. But by "resizable" I didn't mean that growing children of #main-conten element will resize it. I mean literally, by user dragging the bottom-right corner, using jQuery.resizable for that purpose. I.e. the width also can change.